# Printing out a dictionary that contains keys and lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print out a dictionary neatly in python but unsure how to do so.

If I have the dictionary

```
mydict = {'Jackson' :['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 'Jeffery' :['Four', 'Five', 'Six']}
```

How would I print it out like this:

```
Jackson One Two Three

Jeffery Four Five Six
```

Im guessing I have to use a for loop, just struggling to figure out how to print out the list component.

Comment: A `for` loop would be a good idea to pursue, have a go and if you struggle come back with a specific issue. Note: `str.join()` may also be in your future.

Comment: I understand the downvote, but if you step back, it seems like this could be a useful Q/A unless it were a dup.  Seems a bit canonical.

Comment: you should try and tell if something specific impedes your progress

Answer (score 1):

another way to solve this problem,

```
def printDictionary(mydict):
    for i in mydict.keys():
        print(i + " " + (" ".join(mydict[i])))

mydict = mydict = {'Jackson' :['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 'Jeffery' :['Four', 'Five', 'Six']}
printDictionary(mydict)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3.6, you may use an `f` string

```
>>> mydict = {
...     'Jackson' :['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 
...     'Jeffery' :['Four','Five', 'Six']
... }

>>> for k,v in mydict.items():
...     print(f"{k} {' '.join(v)}")
... 
Jackson One Two Three
Jeffery Four Five Six
```

In older versions of 3.x, you can use format by keys

```
>>> for k,v in mydict.items():
...     print("{k} {vstr}".format(k=k, vstr=" ".join(v)))
... 
Jackson One Two Three
Jeffery Four Five Six
```

or positional

```
>>> for k,v in mydict.items():
...     print("{} {}".format(k, " ".join(v)))
... 
Jackson One Two Three
Jeffery Four Five Six
```

If you want to be terse, you could also just use tuple unpacking (but it's pretty inflexible if you need to change the output format)

```
>>> for k, v in mydict.items():
...     print(k, *v)
... 
Jackson One Two Three
Jeffery Four Five Six
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in mydict:
    print(key,end=' ')
    for i in mydict[key]:
        print(i,end='')
    print("\n")
```